# Does Android 4.4.3 support Bluetooth Low Energy in peripheral mode

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, bluetooth

(Re-post from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24049823/does-android-4-4-3-support-bluetooth-low-energy-in-peripheral-mode):

We know that Android until 4.4.2 does not support Bluetooth Low Energy in peripheral mode (see [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=59693)).

As the OP said, from those commits https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/ee0b3e9 looks like they added the feature.

Does anybody have any information on this?

Comment: That's not true check [Android Developer](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html). BLE support from 4.3 onward.

Comment: 4.3 supports BLE in _central mode_. BLE _peripheral mode_ is only supported in 5.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Google I/O, peripheral mode for BLE will only be supported with Android L. (Source: https://plus.google.com/117159045047546859181/posts/79nqfUwxeZK)

[Another source](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.at/2014/06/developer-preview-and-play-services-5.html) says it clear:

> BLE Peripheral Mode — Android devices can now function in Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) peripheral mode. Apps can use this capability to broadcast their presence to nearby devices — for example, you can now build apps that let a device to function as a pedometer or health monitor and transmit data to another BLE device.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like they have made a number of changes and fixes for Bluetooth and BLE. The changelog is [here](https://funkyandroid.com/aosp-KOT49H-KTU84L.html). You can just do a search for bluetooth in that document. [This](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/ee0b3e9) might interest you too. (I'm not sure what they mean by "do not merge")

Comment: AFAIK "do not merge" has no meaning here, thats just left over from previous in-house processes